# How to implement Autocomplete Textbox using sql server 2008 in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need implement Auto complete text box,values getting from database (Server) using Asp.Net MVC3, using javascript or jQuery. So please try help me with source.

I am using ASP.Net MVC3.

Comment: sorry,I need jquery also

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What searches did you perform in this aspect? Maybe someone already implemented this? Maybe even there's the exact same question already asked here? I bet 5 bucks there is the exact same question.

Comment: Recently i am started Mvc3 learning, I need autocomplete extender textbox. I created hardcoded textbox, but i want using database

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery.autocomplete.js

```
var HiddenInput = $("#hiddenInput");
var source = "@Url.Action("Autocomplete","Autocomplete")";
$("input").autocomplete({
            autoFocus: false,
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: source,
            search: function (event, ui) {
                HiddenInput.val("");
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                if (HiddenInput.val() == "")
                    $(this).val("");
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.Name);
                HiddenInput.val(ui.item.Value);

                return false;
            }

        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.Name+ "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        };

        })
```

Comment: Hi Yorgo,Can u give me full source code

Comment: do you want action code?

Comment: I need Total code for developing autocomplete extender textbox